# How Can I Remove Multiple Sections of Characters From a String? PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to strip all the image tags from a series of strings from a database. Below works fine for a single image: (FYI - No other tags in the strings end with `/>`)

```
 $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM events ORDER BY date ASC");
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
             $content = $row['text'];
             if(strpos($content, '<img') !== false){
                $point1 = strpos($content, '<img');
                $point2 = strpos($content, '/>');
                $cleaned = substr_replace($content, "", $point1, $point2-1);
              }
                echo $cleaned;
        }
```

I tried to loop through to clean the string multiple times, to no avail. Just gives me the same result with only the first image tag removed:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM events ORDER BY date ASC");
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
             $content = $row['text'];
             if(strpos($content, '<img') !== false){
                $img_ct = substr_count($content, '<img');
                for($i=0;$i<$img_ct;$i++){  
                  $point1 = strpos($content, '<img');                                                            
                  $point2 = strpos($content, '/>');
                  $cleaned = substr_replace($content, "", $point1, $point2-1);
                }
             } 
            echo $cleaned;  
         }
```

Is there a way to strip out multiple sections of text within a thread? Looping or otherwise?

This is my first question, by the way. Love this site. You've all helped me tremendously.

Comment: use preg_replace ? or str_replace ?

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php).

```
if(strpos($content, '<img') !== false) {
     $cleaned = preg_replace('/<img[^>]+\/>/', '', $content);
}
```

Comment: Perfect. I'm a bit of a php novice, and haven't really delved into regular expressions thoroughly. Thanks very much for the quick assist.